# PHP: var from string in function no working

Tags: php

this function does not return the result, what could I be doing wrong?

```
<?php

function iisset($name){
    return ${$name}; // "${$name}" does not work
}
$hola = 1;
echo iisset("hello");
```

Note: it works correctly if it is not in a function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues going on here.  The first is an issue of scope. Nothing outside the function `iisset($name)` is normally visible to it.  Therefore any variable defined outside `iisset($name)` can't been seen.

So the first step would be to make it global
by adding global ${$name}; to the first line after the function declaration.  The second would be that there is no variable named "hello"  outside the function.  If you are trying to access the `$hola` then I would recommend the following:

```
<?php
function iisset($name){
    global ${$name};
    return ${$name}; // "${$name}" does not work
}
$hola = 1;
echo iisset("hola");
```

Comment: Incredible, with the global the problem is solved, thank you very much